# Get selected image URL from wp.media.editor.attachment into text input fails. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, wp-editor, media-modal

I have placed a media button as a **post meta field** to insert an image URL into a text field when **Insert Into Page** button is clicked. It works up to the point of opening the media repository window, selecting image and insert, however no value is passed to the input field.

### [image: media button]

[image: media repository]

---

**Expected result**

The result should be that the URL along with media ID are inserted as
`https://avalon.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/scp7147prko31.jpg|12` but no value is returned. I can enter a URL manually and the data is saved.

[image: expected result]

I have scanned my code thoroughly and tried numerous methods with the javascript where I figure is the source of the failure. The debug console indicates that there is a fault with an expected function named `tabs` associated with the plugin **classic editor** but I cannot locate such. I even disabled the plugin and the failure persists.

**I've stared down the code for now 4 hours and cannot define a solution, so I am seeking assistance to resolve.**

**Console Log**

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function
<anonymous> https://avalon.com/dev/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit&classic-editor&message=1:300
jQuery 2
    mightThrow
    process
post.php:300:21
```

#### The code

```
public static function mediabutton($fname, $value) 
{
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', function() {
        wp_enqueue_media();
    });
    
    $js = '<script>
    jQuery(function($) 
    {
        if( $(".mb-insertimg").length > 0 ) 
        {
            if( typeof wp !== "undefined" && wp.media && wp.media.editor ) {
                $(".mb-insertimg").on("click", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment) {
                        $("#mb-socialimg").val(wp.media.attachment(attachment.id).get("url")+"|"+attachment.id);
                    };
                    wp.media.editor.open($(this));
                    return false;
                });
            }
        }
        
        $("a.clearit").on("click", function() { 
            $("#mb-socialimg").val(""); 
        });
    });
    </script>';
    
    $thumb= $imgUrl='';
    if( !empty($value) ) 
    {
        if( strstr($value, '|') ) {
            list($imgUrl, $imgId) = explode('|', $value);
            $tid = wp_get_attachment_image_src($imgId, 'thumbnail');
            $thumb = '<img src="'.$tid[0].'" />';
        }else{
            $imgUrl = $value;
            $thumb = '<img src="'.$value.'" />';
        }
    }
    
    $img = '
    <div class="mb-imginsert">
    <span><input type="text" id="mb-socialimg" name="'.$fname.'" value="'.$imgUrl.'" /></span>
    <span><button class="mb-insertimg button">Select Image</button></span>
    <span><a class="button clearit dashicons dashicons-no" style="width: auto;" href="javascript:;"></a></span>
    <span>'.$thumb.'</span>
    </div>
    '.$js;
    
    return $img;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there was a conflict in the complex string

```
$("#mb-socialimg").val(wp.media.attachment(attachment.id).get("url")+"|"+attachment.id);
```

I changed to the following and now it all works well

```
$("#mb-socialimg").val(attachment.url+"|"+attachment.id);
```